# Assinaturas retornam o 'INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA' nulo usando 'In-app Billing V3'

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-billing

Estou implementando a compra de Assinaturas em uma aplicação Android.

Até o momento, as ordens de pagamento já estão configuradas no 'Google Play Console de Desenvolvedor' e eu consigo debitar o valor definido em cada uma das SKU no cartão de crédito.

Ao final disto, quero pegar os dados do JSON que deveriam vir `"INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA"` dentro do `onActivityResult` da aplicação.

Porém, ao realizar a chamada no `bundle`, não retorna nada.

Todos os lugares do código onde deveriam retornar os dados da compram sempre retornam um valor Nulo.

Mas mesmo assim a compra é debitada do meu cartão. O que me leva ao processo de correr até o console do '`Google Wallet`' e cancelar o faturamento.

Eis aqui o que estou fazendo no momento:

> Defini o serviço antes do OnCreate.

```
ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };
```

> No 'onCreate' eu defino o SKU que vem de outra Activity, inicio o
>   Servico e a configuração do IABHelper.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        .
        skuSubs = getIntent().getExtras().getString("SKU_TYPE");

        bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
              public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " result);
                }else{             
                    Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                }
              }
            });
    }
```

> aqui eu defino o método que será usado no `onClick` da minha Activity
>   para abrir a janela de Dialogo da assinatura. (o developerPayload é
>   gerado em outro lugar do código)

```
public void buyClick(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, skuSubs, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, developerPayload);
    }
```

> No método 'onActivityResult' eu capturo o retorno do
>   'INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA' pelo 'Bundle'.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {     
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          }
          if(data.getExtras()!=null){
              Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
              editText.setText(bundle.getString("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA"));
          }else{
              editText.setText("null");
          }
    }
```

> Aqui o 'mPurchaseFinishedListener' trata os dados da compra. Em testes
>   anteriores, tentei capturar os dados pela classe 'Purchase', porém sem
>   sucesso.

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }else 
            if (purchase.getSku().equals(skuSubs)) {
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
            }
        }
    };

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
       public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
           if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle failure
                return;
            } else {
              mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(skuSubs), mConsumeFinishedListener);
          }
       }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    //ok msg
                 } else {
                     //fail msg
                 }
            }
        };
```

> No 'onDestroy' eu termino com o 'Serviço' e com o 'IABHelper'.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) unbindService(mServiceConn);
    if (mHelper != null) {
        mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }       
}
```

> No meu 'AndroidManifest.xml' estão definidos:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
   ...
    <service android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService" />
```

Quando configuro isso, dependendo do SKU que é enviado na Activity anterior eu recebo os dados da compra corretamente.

Quando faço a compra, ela é determinada como concluída e depois não recebo o resultado da compra.

Abro o Developer Console e logo após entro no Wallet para cancelar a Assinatura que foi debitada.

Como eu faço essa requisição dentro da aplicação? Não consigo pegar o retorno da compra até agora.